# After Mar-Vell was murdered, how come the Tesseract got transported back to her secret laboratory?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

I believe that when Yon-Rogg attempted to kill Danvers, she responded immediately by shooting right at the heart of the light speed engine where the **Tesseract** was located. The sudden explosion then unleashed a massive outburst of Tesseract energy which was absorbed by Danvers into her genetic code leaving her with newly gained cosmic powers. Then Minn-Erva intercepted and informed Rogg that the **energy core** has been destroyed. Then they took Danvers to Hala.

I think at that time,  the **Tessaract** which is **indestructible** was somewhere on Earth where those incident took place. And in the later scenes I wonder **how the tesseract got spotted in Mar-Vell's laboratory instead** of being **at the same place** where **Mar-Vell** was **murdered**. How come the Tessaract got to Mar-Vell's lab? Who took it there? How was it transported?

Comment: FWIW you don't need to bold every word with `**`, just put it at the start and end of the bold run.

Comment: Also, the stones are not completely indestructible.  (End Game spoilers).

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I like how you give a spoiler, then immediately make it worse by telling us which movie you spoilt 

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Yeah, but it's like in the first 10 minutes, and honestly if you haven't seen it by now, that's kind of on you...

Answer (score 31):

The core, or Tesseract, was never in the ship that was shot down by Yon-Rogg and later blown up by Carol.  Rather, the ship used an engine that was developed using the Tesseract as its power source. This is made a bit clearer later on when talking to Talos:

> **Talos:** She wanted you to help us find the core.
>
> **Carol:** Well, I already destroyed it.
>
> **Talos:** No, you destroyed the engine. The core that powered it is in a remote location. If you help us decode those coordinates, we can find it.
>
> <sub>*Captain Marvel*</sub>

Comment: Yes, it seems similar to how in another movie Dr Zola used the Tesseract to charge up super-batteries to power Red Skull's army.